# How can we use IR sensor in MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, sensors, app-inventor, infrared

We can use in MIT App Inventor 2 these sensors:

[image: MIT AI2 Sensors]

Can we use another sensor e.g. `IR Sensor` or `Step Sensor`?

And if we can, how can we do it?

Which component should we use to access other sensors?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to be more clear about what you are asking.  For instance, I could completely answer your question with a simple, "Yes you can", however, I rather suspect your question is HOW.  If so, then ask that.

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I'm editing now. (I'm sorry, i weak in English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `IR component` available in MIT App Inventor, but you can create your own App Inventor Extension.

[More information about how to create an extension see here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Ip2AX036d0U/5NJlAEbFCgAJ), 
however that will be more advanced and will require some Java skills...

As an example, see my [Barometer Sensor Extension](https://puravidaapps.com/barometer.php).